# Drupal: Views showing duplicate content for anonymous users but not authenicated users

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

I have a strange problem with views. For anonymous users it is listing the results twice and for authenticated users only once? Any idea what might be going wrong? I have cleared the cache.

Comment: You have this problem with all views or with a specific one. Post view setup screenshot please.

Comment: All views are having this problem

Comment: Are you using (or have you used) any access modules with that site? Also, can you check if your 'users' table still contains an entry for the anonymous user, with uid = 0 (its a wild guess, and never happened to me, but it has happened that this entry got deleted, which causes weird behavior all around a Drupal site)

Comment: what kind of content are you indexing in your view. sounds like a wonky field based around user. did you try setting the distinct flag? 

Without view/site config one can only stab in the dark.

Comment: Possible trouble with node_access module.

Comment: Domain Access is being used. I have rebuilt permission but still an issue

Comment: @Jason the distinct flag did work. Still not sure why there are two listings. I think it could be domain module related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was due to the Domain Access module making content appear for each of the two domain when the content was the same.